# Stripping shortcodes AND the content inside of them in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress you can use strip_shortcodes($content) to remove the shortcode brackets when showing an excerpt of a post, but what about the content inside that shortcode?

Usually shortcodes are things like buttons/youtube links/etc, so the contents are often "Click here" or a youtube url, which with strip_shortcodes ends up in an excerpt like this:

Raw post: "[button]CLICK HERE[/button] lorem ipsum aptem"

Excerpt output: "CLICK HERE lorem ipsum aptem"

How can I remove the Button contents (CLICK HERE) as well as the brackets?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes and my testing it does remove the shortcodes and the content.